# Structure for recurring unlimited voting contests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, voting

I am in the planning stages of building an app where all users (registered or not) can vote every minute or so. The voting window should last a set period of time (for ex. 1 month). At which point a winning entity is defined and the voting period resets and starts all over. Visitors can then leave comments about the winner for that period. *My question is what do you think is the best way to set something like this up?*

Here are my current thoughts, but doesn't seem ideal:

1) **Vote model**: entity_id, contest_id, user_id (optional), created_at, ip_address

- search for ip in db on new vote and see if time diff greater than allowed vote time limit between user votes
- use CAPTCHA every variable number of votes to ensure human
- calculate current vote count by counting all the entries for an entity for a contest

2) **Contest model**: start and end datetime

- have a weekly or monthly cron job create the newest instance
- votes find current contest if current date in between these 2 dates
- individual model allows to create attributes to the contest(for example, special kinds of contests)

3) **Winner model**: contest_id, entity_id

- allows for users to comments on past contest winners

Comment: what do you mean by best way? Architecture? What language to use to implement it?

Comment: Architecture. I'm going to use ROR. I showed the model/db structure I'm considering above. My question is there a better way to structure it?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details, I would go with something along the lines of:

```
class User
  has_many :votes
  has_many :comments
  has_many :contests, :through => :votes

class Vote
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :contest

class Contest
  has_many :votes
  has_many :users, :through => :votes

class Comment
  belongs_to :user
```

This way, you can have `@user.votes, @contest.votes, @contest.users`, etc.

I don't see the need for a Winners model, since that can just be a boolean in Users.  If you needed to, you could always have a Winnings model that belonged to both Users and Contests to link the two.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. The organization/entity is voted on and wins. So, a new instance of the winnings model with the winning organization/entity would be set at the end of the contest.